# How do I connect different swift jpanels in the Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In my program, I have all the different " screens" that I want. They are all under the same project and each has a button or two that directs the user to another page. How can I get it so clicking the "Coaches Corner" button will have the Coaches corner file pop up?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should be using a `CardLayout`. A `CardLayout` allows you to swap panels.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.